# Change Position of legend in vue-chartJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I'm new to Vue-ChartJs, and got really curious about this:

[image: Legend position]

How do I change the legend position to the bottom of the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your chart options object use this:

```js
const chartOptions = {
  // other options...
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So my problem was i have a typo on the word 'legend', and typing it as 'legends' instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
chartOptions: {
// other options...
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'right'
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How did you figure this out? I don't seen anything about this in the docs https://vue-chartjs.org/api/